# Read xml file and put values into sql table by MERGE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, merge, insert-update

I got an XML file looking like this:

```
<ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency">
                <Currency>
                    <IntComp>08</IntComp>
                    <Active>1</Active>
                    <Currency>USD</Currency>
                    <Text>US Dollar</Text>
                </Currency>
            </ns0:Currency>
```

Edit: I need to take all these fields inside Currency and fit them into table, this should work for all files looking like this. Not only these values.

I want to put these values into my sql table which have the same columns, i would like to Merge these values into the table so it will Update if the IntComp value && Currency match match with another file. And it will Insert if the file doesnt match.

I havent figured out how to write this sql query.

EDIT: 
The tables look like this.

```
dbo.Integration
ID | XMLData | Entity | EntityId | Action | ....
```

XMLData is the string with XMLData that i want to send to another table and pick out those node from that field.

The other table:

```
dbo.Currency
ID | IntComp | Active | Currency | Text
```

This is what ive been trying so far:

```
SELECT XMLData.value('(/ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency/Currency/IntComp/node())[1]', 'int') as intComp,
       XMLData.value('(/ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency/Currency/Active/node())[1]', 'int') as Active,
       XMLData.value('(/ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency"/Currency/Currency/node())[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Currency,
       XMLData.value('(/ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency"/Currency/text/node())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') as Active
FROM dbo.Integration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this..

```
DECLARE @DocHandle AS INT;
DECLARE @XmlDocument AS NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @XmlDocument = '<ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency"><Currency><IntComp>08</IntComp><Active>1</Active><Currency>USD</Currency><Text>US Dollar</Text></Currency></ns0:Currency>';
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument,'<ns0:Currency xmlns:ns0="http://bla.bla.Currency"/>';

MERGE INTO tmp1 AS TGT
USING (SELECT IntComp,Active,Currency,Text FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/ns0:Currency/Currency',11) WITH (IntComp INT,Active INT,Currency varchar(10),Text nvarchar(100))) 
AS SRC ON SRC.IntComp = TGT.IntComp and SRC.Currency = TGT.Currency 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET TGT.IntComp = SRC.IntComp , TGT.Currency = SRC.Currency 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
VALUES(SRC.IntComp,SRC.Active, SRC.Currency, SRC.Text);

select * from tmp1
```

Comment: I need to add alot of xml files looking like this but with different values. So need it to work in general for this type of xml file.

Comment: you can create a stored procedure which takes input as xml what you have do the merge on whatever table you have to insert.

Comment: Currently im SELECTing the xml strings from another table, i need to sort out the values so they will fit into the new table.

Comment: Now you have enough to comment.  :) Enjoy.  ( you should probably remove that other answer)

Comment: @paqogomez .. thanks  and i removed the other answer.

Comment: Im trying to use this... Adding SET @XmlDocument = (SELECT XMLData FROM dbo.Integration) and im Merge into dbo.Currency AS TGT. but im getting "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: does dbo.integration table has mutliple rows, if yes this will not work.

SET XmlDocument = (SELECT XMLData FROM dbo.Integration)

if it has only one row..you can try this.

SELECT XmlDocument = XMLData FROM dbo.Integration